# Knockout: getting data

Tags: knockout.js

I need to get, for each student, data about "Note", but the method I've tried doesnt seem to work... I'd appreciate any kind of help or advices.

```
 <table data-bind="foreach: students">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nume</th>
            <th>Prenume</th>
            <th>Data</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" size="1" data-bind="value: StudId" disabled="disabled"></td>
            <td><input type="text" size="60" data-bind="value: Nume" disabled="disabled"></td>
            <td><input type="text" size="60" data-bind="value: Prenume" disabled="disabled"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="15" data-bind="value: Data" disabled="disabled">
                <input data-bind="click: $parent.deleteStudent.bind($parent, $data.StudId)" type="button" value="Sterge" class="button button1" id="sterge" />
                <input data-bind="click: function() { $parent.loadNote.bind($parent, $data.StudId)(); alert( // I wanna display the received json in this alert box ); }" type="button" class="button button2" value="Note" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And Knockout one:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var uri = 'api/student';

        var StudentsViewModel = function () {
            this.students = ko.observableArray();
            this.note = ko.observableArray();

            this.loadNote();
            this.loadStudents();
        };

        StudentsViewModel.prototype.loadStudents = function () {
            var self = this;
            $.getJSON(uri, function (data) {
                self.students(data);
            });
        };

        StudentsViewModel.prototype.loadNote = function (id) {
            var self = this;
            $.getJSON(uri + '/' + id, function (data) {
                self.note(data);
            });
        };
// Apply bindings
        ko.applyBindings(new StudentsViewModel());
```

I've got a list of students and by pressing on the "Note" button, I wanna display details about them in an alert box.

EDIT:

```
var StudentsViewModel = function () {      
        this.students = ko.observableArray();
        this.note = ko.observableArray();


        this.loadStudents();
        this.loadNote();
    };

    StudentsViewModel.prototype.loadStudents = function () {
      var  self = this;
        $.getJSON(uri, function (data) {
            self.students(data);
        });
    };
```

JSON Student model:

```
{
    "StudId": 7,
    "Nume": "Mihalache",
    "Prenume": "Florin",
    "Data": "2016-07-05T12:00:00"
  }
```

JSON Note Model:

```
{
  "Student": "Mihalache Florin",
  "NotaId": 1,
  "Materie": "Matematica",
  "Nota": 10,
  "Status": true
}
```

Comment: What console error are you getting? Please also post what your data looks like from the 'loadStudents' ajax response. What I can see from your  html data-bind's is that '$parent.deleteStudent' doesn't exist in your KO ViewModel. That will stop the processing of data.

Comment: @Ben it does exist, but I didnt post it here. I only dont know how can I get a json from '/api/student/id' and format it into an alert box, the other methods are working properly w/o console errors. The error im receiving right now is badrequest().

Comment: @BenSewards I've edited the question and posted how im getting the data for students.

Comment: You already posted the loadStudents method. I was asking for the JSON response of 'data'.

Comment: @BenSewards I've edited the post again.

Comment: @BenSewards How can I fix it to show details about the student ?

Comment: I've provided an answer. Please review the changes in the jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a separate API call for the student's notes, you're going to have to abstract your model a little bit more so that you can fill in that particular students note information when the 2nd api call is made after loading all of the students.

Here's the result on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x8231L6d/5/). There's a couple code changes to note here:

- Dummy data replaced the ajax calls
- Defined a student object with an observable note property
- Added a p tag with data-bind text for each student note (you can take this a step further and add a data-bind visible to the note click button for after the student note is returned)

```js
var Student = function(id, first, last, date) {
  this.StudId = id;
  this.Nume = first;
  this.Prenume = last;
  this.Data = date;

  this.Note = ko.observable("");
}

var StudentsViewModel = function() {
  this.students = ko.observableArray();
  this.note = ko.observable("");
  this.loadStudents();
};

StudentsViewModel.prototype.loadStudents = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.students([
    new Student(7, "Mihalache", "Florin", "2016-07-05T12:00:00"),
    new Student(7, "Ben", "Florin", "2016-07-05T12:00:00"),
    new Student(7, "Jill", "Florin", "2016-07-05T12:00:00")]);
};

StudentsViewModel.prototype.loadNote = function(student, event) {
  var self = this;
  var ajaxNote = ""; // switch out for ajax response data
  var studeId= student.StudId;
  
  if (studeId === 7) ajaxNote = "note for 7";
  else if (studeId === 8) ajaxNote = "note for 8";
  else if (studeId === 9) ajaxNote = "note for 9";
  
  student.Note(ajaxNote);
  console.log(studeId + ": " + ajaxNote);
  self.note(ajaxNote)
};

// Apply bindings
ko.applyBindings(new StudentsViewModel());
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

table td {
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table data-bind="foreach: students">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Nume</th>
    <th>Prenume</th>
    <th>Data</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="1" data-bind="value: StudId" disabled="disabled">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="60" data-bind="value: Nume" disabled="disabled">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="60" data-bind="value: Prenume" disabled="disabled">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="15" data-bind="value: Data" disabled="disabled">
      <input data-bind="click: $parent.loadNote" type="button" class="button button2" value="Note" />
      <p data-bind="text: $data.Note"></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p data-bind="text: note"></p>
```

Comment: No problem. Any reason you placed the functions on the prototype instead of directly in the ViewModel?

Comment: Not really ... I know I should have placed the functions in the ViewModel, but Ive been "taught" using prototype so I guess I've made it a habit.
I'm a beginner in all this, but I'm doing my best to learn. Seems like stackoverflow is the friendliest community I've ever joined.